# Fetch users that logged in last month and current month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have only two columns, one with user ID and another with the times he logged in. What I need is to compare wether each user did login in the last month and again in the current month.

```
UserId  LoginDatetime
207     1/25/2021 21:04
207     2/8/2021 14:59
207     2/8/2021 14:59
207     2/16/2021 19:54
209     11/12/2018 18:33
```

I'm new to mySQL so I'm clueless as to how to start this...

What I want to see as result, ideally, would be a table with unique users, and a column showing the result of wether or not the user logged in both months:

```
UserId  Logged in both months
207      No
209      No
```

Thanks for the attention!

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT MONTH(LoginDatetime)) = 2`

Comment: PS. Shown datatime format is not legal for MySQL.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use aggregation and conditional logic:

```
select userid,
       (case when sum(last_day(LoginDatetime) = last_day(curdate())) and
                  sum(last_day(LoginDatetime) = last_day(curdate()) - interval 1 month)
             then 'yes' else 'no'
        end)
from t
group by userid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this

For MySQL -

```
Select distinct userId, 
CASE 
WHEN EXISTS (Select 1 from UserLogin ul1 where ul1.userId = ul.userId and 
DATE_FORMAT(ul1.LoginDatetime,'%m%y') =  DATE_FORMAT(SYSDATE(),'%m%y')) AND
EXISTS (Select 1 from UserLogin ul1 where ul1.userId = ul.userId and 
DATE_FORMAT(ul1.LoginDatetime,'%m%y') =  DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(SYSDATE(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH),'%m%y'))
THEN 'Y'
ELSE 'N'
END 
AS LoggedInBothMonths
from UserLogin ul
```

For Oracle -

```
Select distinct userId, 
CASE 
WHEN EXISTS (Select 1 from UserLogin ul1 where ul1.userId = ul.userId and 
to_char(ul1.LoginDatetime,'MMYY') =  to_char(SYSDATE,'MMYY')) AND
EXISTS (Select 1 from UserLogin ul1 where ul1.userId = ul.userId and 
to_char(ul1.LoginDatetime,'MMYY') =  to_char(add_months(sysdate, -1),'MMYY'))
THEN 'Y'
ELSE 'N'
END 
AS LoggedInBothMonths
from UserLogin ul
```

Comment: This question is tagged to MYSql, add_months() is not a function in MYSql.

Comment: Updated my answer for MySQL as well, thanks for pointing it out